# java class property binding to swing component

Tags: java, swing, binding

I'm coming from .net world, but I have to make a small GUI application in Java.
I would like to achieve that I have a class with some properties and I want to bind the properties to swing components (textfield, combo box) on a JDialog, JFrame.

There are many threads in the net talking about this, but I was not able to achieve the stuff to be working on my case. 
I have a class with a property PropertyChangeSupport, and addPropertyChangeListener and removePropertyChangeListener methods.
In the GUI I could bind the JTextField text attribute to the class instance property. the JDialog is implementing the PropertyChangeListener

but if I write something to the text box nothing is updating in the class property.

Can you point me a complete tutorial about this issue?

thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to also look at using jgoodies (its a very good binding framework for swing gui applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "but if I write something to the text box nothing is updating in the class property."

You're probably going to want to implement a `DocumentListener` to listen for changes in the underlying document of the text field. Every time the document changes, for instance the typing in of a letter, a `DocumentEvent` will be fired. You can see [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)